# including php file From a static class method

Tags: php, class, static, include

I have 2 php files. I am unable to get B's global variable from A's static method:

**A.php**

```
class c_A
  { public static function f_A()
      { include_once( "B.php" ) ;
        print f_B() ;
      }
  }
c_A::f_A( ); // only prints "B : "
```

**B.php**

```
$gvs = "global variable from B" ;

function f_B()
  { return "B : " . $GLOBALS[ "gvs" ] ;
  }
```

Comment: How are you "unable" to do it? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: no errors ... but I am only getting "B : " to print out ... should be "B : global variable from B"

Comment: Have you tried enabling the error report? `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of both pages?

Comment: It doesn't get declared as global variable just because its the first line in the include script. It's still executed in the local variable scope of the `f_A()` method. (There are a few duplicate questions on this..)

Comment: I added it to both, but no errors showing, nor errors in the browser's 'view source' ...

Comment: this has nothing to do with `oop` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$GLOBALS[ "gvs" ]` is empty because you calling `B.php` inside function. So `$gvs` variable is not declaring as global variable. If you include `B.php` outside of class at `A.php` you will get result:

**A.php**

```
include_once( "B.php" ) ;
class c_A
  { public static function f_A()
      { 
        print f_B() ;
      }
  }
c_A::f_A( ); // will prints "B : global variable from B"
```